# Magento aggregate and between collections?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, collection, query

1) How to write the below SQL query in Magento collection :

```
SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE active=0 AND '2014-07-08' between 'not_available_from_date' and 'not_available_to_date'
```

2) Also how to write this SQL query in Magento Collection :

```
Select sum(qty + product_id - any_other_columns) as total from table2  GROUP BY product_id;
```

Without using **->columns('  ')** function.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a model mapped to your `table1` and one mapped to `table2` you can try something like this.

```
$date = '2014-07-08';
$collection = Mage::getModel('[module]/table1')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('active', 0)
    ->addFieldToFilter('not_available_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $date))
    ->addFieldToFilter('not_available_to_date', array('date' => true, 'from' => $date));
```

And for the second one.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[module]/table2')->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('total', 'SUM({{qty}} + {{product_id}} - {{any_other_columns}})', array('{{qty}}'=>'qty', '{{product_id}}'=>'product_id', '{{any_other_columns}}'=>'any_other_columns'));
//since SUM requires a GROUP BY...group by some column
$collection->getSelect()->group('product_id');
```

The examples above are for flat entities.

If you have an EAV entity similar to products or categories use

`addAttributeToFilter` instead of `addFieldToFilter`

`addExpressionAttributeToSelect` instead of `addExpressionFieldToSelect`

**EDIT**

After an other investigation I found that for flat entities you can use directly the column names. The attribute placeholders `{{...}}` are needed only for EAV entities.

So your second collection should look like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[module]/table2')->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('total', 'SUM(qty + product_id - any_other_columns)', array('qty', 'product_id', 'any_other_columns'));
$collection->getSelect()->group('product_id');
```

The third parameter for `addExpressionFieldToSelect` is required but it can be an empty array. for `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` that last parameter should contain the mapping between the placeholders and the attribute codes. In this case seams that they are useless. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: @VijayS. Did it work?

Comment: First Query working fine. The second one when i execute as query working fine.But i use getData() in this collection its not return a value.

Comment: @VijayS What happens if instead of `getData` you loop through the collection like this: `foreach ($collection as $item){Mage::log($item->getData())}`

Comment: I have tried that above code, But i didn't return any value.

Comment: @VijayS. You can try to see how the query looks like `echo $collection->getSelect()`. That should give you an idea if something is wrong. You may even run it manually to see the result.

Comment: SELECT `main_table`.*, SUM({{varievt_id}} + {{product_id}} - {{new_qty}}) AS `total` FROM `product_special_qty_dates` AS `main_table` WHERE (active = '0') AND (qty_available_from_date <= '2014-07-17 00:00:00') AND (qty_available_to_date >= '2014-07-17 00:00:00') GROUP BY `product_id`

Comment: @VijayS. I've updated the answer with what I just found out. See if this works for the second table.

Comment: Awesome, Second Query working fine.
once again Thanks @marius